# jQuery element[attribute=something] vs element.class performance

Tags: jquery, performance, class, selector

I am wondering which way would end up being faster, selecting elements by:

```
$('element[href=#my_link]');
```

or:

```
$('element.my_class');
```

I don't like repeating myself when I write code, so I prefer to write it the first way for the most part because then I can add information to it like:

```
<a href="#delete_1">Delete</a>


$('a[href^=#delete]');
```

and then split it up so that I have all of the information that I need once it is clicked, or whatever the action may be. Am I sacrificing overall performance because of this?

(I guess I could rewrite it as class="delete" href="#1")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- selecting an Element by class needs :
  453 ms

  - selecting an Element by element + search needs 578 ms

both in FireFox.

Checkout this great Webpage for more tests:

[Jquery Performance](http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19)